# Why Union[List[List[int]], List[int]] is casted to List[Union[List[List[int]], List[int]]]? (Correct use of type hints)

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have following code:

```
from typing import Union,List,Any
v: Union[list[list[int]],list[int]] = [-1,3,1,6,-5] # Create a list of inst
if not isinstance(v[0],list):
    v =[v]
v =[v] # Cast list of ints to list of list of ints
print(v)
```

`mypy` complains about it in the following way:

```
functions.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment 
(expression has type "List[Union[List[List[int]], List[int]]]", 
variable has type "Union[List[List[int]], List[int]]")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I probably do not understand how type hints work but I really can not understand why assigning the new `v` variable this way makes mypy complain, because the end object is actually a `list[list[int]]`.
Can anybody explain?

*PS*

I want to add a note: I encountered this issue while adding type hinting to some code that I do not own on github, so I can not really touch the "logic" of it.

Comment: Likely because you've said `v` can be a nested list or flat list, but then you say `v=[v]`. If `v` were already a nested list (which you said it might be), it's now a *triply* nested list, which you've said `v` isn't allowed to be. So that line may violate the type hint.

Comment: thats a great point, any Idea how to work arround it?Since in the catual code that line gets called just if v is not a list of lists

Comment: I don't use mypy, but it probably has the concept of a "type guard"/"type narrowing". You just need to make it clearer to mypy what the possible types are there.

Comment: Or create a new variable with a different typehint instead of reassigning `v`.

Comment: Thats the easiest solve I just can't do that, since this is preparing a pull request that should just add the type hinting

Comment: Just leave this un-hinted, then.

Comment: I think you'll need to make some minor changes to the code here to use those typehints. Otherwise, the hints are lying. I would think you would need a type guard there regardless for the logic.

Comment: @user2357112 well thats for sure a fix :) Thanks for the input to both of you, I will see what I can do!

Comment: I added a type guard, still not solving the issue

Comment: is solved by changing `v = [v] ` to `v = [[*v]] ` , not clear why

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Issue is solved by changing `v = [v]` to `v=[[*v]]`.
Not clear why...